# Unable to acquire a symbol table lock because it is already locked by. error while building VS DB Project 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Can someone help me how to solve the error below while building the VS 2005 DB project.

> Unable to acquire a symbol table lock because it is already locked by.

I have tried following

1. Refresh/Clean the solution
2. Restarted the system

Then also the same error showing again and again.

Please give me any solution for avoiding this error.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I had some change in scripts. but undo all the changes. then also getting the same .

Comment: Below is a link to an issue. The solution was to upgrade to the RTM. A schema manager locking the schema while updating. The build requires a stable schema and can not continue until the lock is released. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d97f7c7-37f5-49ac-b647-afa3423afbc2/deploy-problem?forum=vstsdb

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution.I was edit a script file in the DB project thats only leads to this issue. So I removed that file from the project and take the Team Explorer > Source Control and  "undo changes" for that file, get latest and check out the file.

After these steps when I build the project, that error is vanished.

I think this will help to others those who are getting this error while after restart the system also.